# Problem using Linq to XML on a Document which Uses Namespace Prefixes

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, svg

I have an SVG file that I've added information to and I am trying to extract information from it using LINQ to XML. This is the first time I've used LINQ.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    *unimportant data*
    <svg:g>
        <svg:path d="m -1117.1429,-101.92353...">
             <body type="static" />
        </svg:path>
        <svg:path d="M 862.85714,112.36218...">
             <body type="kinematic" mass="1.0f" />
        </svg:path>
        <svg:path d="m -1040,-161.92353..." special="startpoint" />
    </svg:g>
    <svg:g>
        <svg:path d="m -714.2857,-90.494957...">
        *more paths*
    </svg:g>
</svg:svg>
```

What I am trying to do is extract all the paths that don't contain a special attribute, get the path data as a string, and get every attribute on the body tag (which the path may or may not have) and put them in a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

This is the code I have so far, it is not returning any errors but it does not extract any paths.

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filename);
XNamespace svg = "svg";

List<SVGPath> svgPaths =
    (from svgPath in document.Descendants(svg + "g").Descendants(svg + "path")
        where svgPath.Attribute("special") == null
        select new SVGPath
        {
            Data = svgPath.Attribute("d").Value,
            Properties = svgPath.Element("body").Attributes().ToDictionary(a => a.Name.LocalName, a => a.Value)
        }).ToList<SVGPath>();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The svg fragment is invalid. Also the markup is setting itself up for some serious pain by using custom attributes on svg elements without ns-prefixing those attributes. If/when svg introduces attributes with the same name your files may break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document never declares the "svg" namespace. That's not going to work.

Comment: I tried just getting the element by using document.Descendants("svg:g") but it gave me an error about using the semicolon in the elemnt name.

Comment: @James: it's a colon, and the document is invalid as you pasted it. Is there some ancestor element that includes `xmlns:svg="some-uri"`? You're just not going to have any luck parsing invalid XML.

Comment: As @John Saunders said - the XML is currently invalid since its missing the namespace declaration - your code works fine for me testing if I replace your root element with `<svg:svg xmlns:svg="svg">`

Comment: Yes sorry, the root element contains that attribute. I've updated the question with that attribute. You can also find the actual document I am working with at http://pastebin.com/KqMnAAu4

Comment: Now the only thing you got to fix is your namespace declaration in code - it has to match the one in your XML